# Joining MYSQL queries problem

Tags: mysql

Above is my query ... but the corresponding names for the observer_ID and staff_ID is in another table called staff. SO some how i need to join (o.observer_ID=s.staff_ID) AND ( o.staff_ID=s.staff_ID) to get the two names of the observer and the person being observed (o.staff_ID). Please help me with it. Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Room, o.Date,o.Module_code,o.observer_ID,o.staff_ID,o.form_id
FROM mbm2_db.observation_details as o,mbm2_db.Staff as s
WHERE o.date = '2011-08-09' and o.Module_code = 'IS5103'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    o.Room, o.Date,o.Module_code,o.observer_ID,o.staff_ID,o.form_id,
    s1.name, s2.name
FROM 
    mbm2_db.observation_details AS o
    LEFT JOIN mbm2_db.Staff AS s1 ON o.observer_ID = s1.staff_ID
    LEFT JOIN mbm2_db.Staff AS s2 ON o.staff_ID = s2.staff_ID
WHERE 
    o.date = '2011-08-09' AND o.Module_code = 'IS5103'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a self inner join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Room, o.Date,o.Module_code, o.observer_ID, o.staff_ID, o.form_id 
FROM mbm2_db.observation_details As o
JOIN mbm2_db.Staff As s ON o.staff_ID = s.staff_ID
JOIN mbm2_db.Staff As b ON b.observer_ID = s.staff_ID
WHERE o.date = '2011-08-09' and o.Module_code = 'IS5103';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT o.Room, o.Date,o.Module_code,o.observer_ID,o.staff_ID,o.form_id 
 FROM mbm2_db.observation_details o, mbm2_db.Staff s 
 WHERE o.date = '2011-08-09' 
  AND o.Module_code = 'IS5103' 
  AND o.staff_ID=s.staff_ID 
  AND o.observer_ID=s.staff_ID
```

Comment: You could have simplified to `o.staff_ID = o.observer_ID`, which should never be true, hence 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Room, o.Date, o.Module_code, o.observer_ID, o.staff_ID, o.form_id 
FROM (mbm2_db.observation_details AS o LEFT JOIN mbm2_db.Staff AS observer ON o.observer_ID = oberver.staff_ID)
    LEFT JOIN mbm2_db.Staff AS observed ON o.staff_ID = observed.staff_ID
WHERE o.date = '2011-08-09' and o.Module_code = 'IS5103'
```

Tell me if it works (and check some values manually).